# How do multiplayer turn based games handle computation

Tags: architecture, data-structure, simulations, turn-based, scalability

I am building a turn based multiplayer simulation game that at the end of each turn takes all of the users inputs/actions then compiles all the data and interactions returning the result of the previous decisions made. My problem is how to scale this out. How do games like civ handle the computation of the game each turn without massive overheads on server computation? My game in specific has an economy with many different factors and values which all interact with each other and can trigger events based on random numbers and thresholds. I need to find a way to handle all of the computation without offloading it all to a server dramatically increasing costs.

Comment: It may be way less than you would expect. Do a small test with a few players/ bots. Increase it and see how many more resources you use.

Comment: Do you currently have an issue with this?

Comment: @Vaillancourt no but I want to future proof this and I'm thinking about this from a scaleability point of view.

Comment: @Zibelas This is a very complex deep global economic simulation with each country having it's own individual economic states and industries which all can potentially interact with each other. In simpler terms think a slightly less in depth real world economy. There are a lot of simulations going on and as the user base grows the server usage would be somewhat exponential i believe. Alone however it would be relatively simple for a computer to handle a single game.

Comment: You can always let one user be the host so the most computations that happen at once are from the single game they are playing. You can still have your servers for match making and from time to time verification.